# Git server's architecture

Tags: git, architecture

We want to have a Git architecture like this. Is this possible? How can we configure the communication between the Git servers? Is there any tool available that can automate the pushing from one to another server?

[image: Git server architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this setup makes sense.

You could automate the push by adding a [post-receive](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#post-receive) hook to the central repository.

Be aware that both server repositories have to be bare in order to reliably push to them. Alternatively you could pull from the second server if it needs an up to date working tree.

Comment: How can I configure the communication between the two repositories? How will I specify that my dev server will push changes on the production server? Will I need to stage the files before committing and pushing?

Comment: The commits are created at the developers box and pushed to the first server. From there you can push them to the second server simply by `git push`. You can log into the first server change to the repository and push to the second server. You can later automate this by using a hook as already mentioned.